# how to parse html by sed - extract two strings delimited by two strings - on different lines, sequentially

Tags: string, bash, sed, extract

I have a bash script:

```
v1='value="'
v2='" type'

do_parse_html_file() {
   sed -n "s/.*${v1}//;s/${v2}.*//p" "${_SCRIPT_PATH}/IBlockListLists.html"|egrep '^http' >${_tmp_file}
}
```

... which is extracting from html file only URLs.
I would like to have on output:

somename URL
somename URL

--- example of the input html file is like the following:

```
</tr>
<tr class="alt01">
<td><b><a href="http://www.iblocklist.com/list.php?list=bcoepfyewziejvcqyhqo">iana-reserved</a></b></td>
<td>Bluetack</td>
<td><img style="border:0;" src="I-BlockList%20%7C%20Lists_files/star_4.png" alt="" height="15" width="75"></td>
<td><input style="width:200px; outline:none; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#ccc;" id="bcoepfyewziejvcqyhqo" readonly="readonly" onclick="select_text('bcoepfyewziejvcqyhqo');" value="http://list.iblocklist.com/?list=bcoepfyewziejvcqyhqo&amp;fileformat=p2p&amp;archiveformat=gz" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt02">
<td><b><a href="http://www.iblocklist.com/list.php?list=cslpybexmxyuacbyuvib">iana-private</a></b></td>
<td>Bluetack</td>
<td><img style="border:0;" src="I-BlockList%20%7C%20Lists_files/star_4.png" alt="" height="15" width="75"></td>
<td><input style="width:200px; outline:none; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#ccc;" id="cslpybexmxyuacbyuvib" readonly="readonly" onclick="select_text('cslpybexmxyuacbyuvib');" value="http://list.iblocklist.com/?list=cslpybexmxyuacbyuvib&amp;fileformat=p2p&amp;archiveformat=gz" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

--- result should be like following:

> iana-reserved http://list.iblocklist.com/?list=bcoepfyewziejvcqyhqo&fileformat=p2p&archiveformat=gz
>   iana-private http://list.iblocklist.com/?list=cslpybexmxyuacbyuvib&fileformat=p2p&archiveformat=gz

---Is it possible to have it by sed on one line command ? If so, please help.

the first part of the list - the "somename" is always first than following by the URL sitting on the next /does not have to be second/ line.

```
>somename   ... is delimited by   'href="URL">'   and   '</a>'       on one line           
>URL ... is always delimited by   'value="'       and   '" type'     on any following line
```

thank you,
kind regards.
M.

Answer (score 2):

With my [cli html parser](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) Xidel it is a single line:

```
xidel "${_SCRIPT_PATH}/IBlockListLists.html" -e '//a/concat(., " ", @href)'
```

Answer (score 1):

[shell](/questions/tagged/shell) is not the right tool to do this.

I can show you some scripts to do it in [python](/questions/tagged/python) or [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) (`ruby`, `java`, `php` too) with a *HTML parser*. These are the right tools for this job.

This is the question maybe the most discussed on this web site, see this [excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/465183)

One of that guys that makes this web site, wrote [this too](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a parser. There are many of them, here an example using `HTML::TokeParser`.

Content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use HTML::TokeParser;

my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new( shift ) || die;

while ( my $tag = $p->get_tag( 'a' ) ) { 
    printf qq|%s %s\n|, $p->get_text, $tag->[1]{href};
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl-5.14.2 script.pl htmlfile
```

That yields:

```
iana-reserved http://www.iblocklist.com/list.php?list=bcoepfyewziejvcqyhqo
iana-private http://www.iblocklist.com/list.php?list=cslpybexmxyuacbyuvib
```